# Bootstrap form-group with labels above inputs and EasyUI controls

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-easyui

I a creating a form where I want to have labels above the inputs. That can be done by using form-group class. Everything works fine, but if I replace standard inputs with EasyUI controls it breaks the expected layout. Here is my code:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Line Height</label>
        <input class="form-control" style="width:200px" id="name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="name1" class="control-label">Padding Top</label>
        <input class="form-control" style="width:200px" id="name1"/>
    </div>
</form>
<form>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="name2" class="control-label">Display Name</label>
        <input class="form-control easyui-textbox" style="width:200px" id="name2" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="name3" class="control-label">Start Screen</label>
        <input class="form-control easyui-textbox" style="width:200px" id="name3"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/quyB6/173/)

When resizing it is also not following proper wrapping. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: when you say it breaks the expected layout, can you expand on that? (i.e. what is the expected layout?) - when i resize the page, smaller, it looks good to me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap the `input`s inside another `div` to maintain `label`s up and prevent collapsing.

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="name2" class="control-label">Display Name</label>
        <div>
            <input class="form-control easyui-textbox" style="width:200px" id="name" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="name3" class="control-label">Start Screen</label>
        <div>
            <input class="form-control easyui-textbox" style="width:200px" id="name1" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[**--> Check JSFiddle here <--**](http://jsfiddle.net/Syden/quyB6/174/)

[image]

Comment: Yes, perfect! Thanks.